# xauth privileges

Tags: twitter, privileges, xauth

to get xauth privileges what we have to send in email to api@twitter.com  ?after how many days we will get that?

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from this site: http://aralbalkan.com/3133 . In the Usage:Overview section.

"Make sure that you include the App ID of your app in your support ticket. The App ID is the number at the end of the URL on your app's Twitter page (e.g., http://twitter.com/oauth_clients/details/your_app_id)"

I've been having issues with a guy over there. He wants to see screenshots of my app and he wants to know what i'm using it for. I made a quick login screen took a pic and sent it. I told him that's all I had. No luck so far. I told him I'm not going to try to make an entire app without being able to connect to Twitter.